# understanding constant pools in Javassist

Tags: java, javassist

I am using Javassist to extend certain classes at runtime .
In a couple of places (in the generation code) I need to create instances of the Javassist `ConstPool` class.
For example, to mark a generated class as `synthetic`, I wrote something like this:

```
CtClass ctClassToExtend = ... //class to extend
CtClass newCtClass = extend(ctClassToExtend, ...); //method to create a new ctClass extending ctClassToExtend
SyntheticAttribute syntheticAttribute = new SyntheticAttribute(ctClassToExtend.getClassFile().getConstPool()); //creating a synthetic attribute using an instance of ConstPool
newCtClass.setAttribute(syntheticAttribute.getName(), syntheticAttribute.get()); //marking the generated class as synthetic
```

This is working as expected, but I have certain doubts about this being entirely correct. Concretely, my main question is:

Is the call to `CtClass.getClassFile().getConstPool()` the correct way to get a constant pool in this example?. If not, what is the general proper way to get the right instance of a constant pool when creating a new class at runtime using Javassist?

Also, I am a bit lost regarding what is happening behind the curtains here: Why do we need a constant pool to create a instance of a synthetic attribute ?, or in general, of any other kind of class attributes ?

Thanks for any clarification.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't know if you're still interested in the answer, but at least might help others that
find this question.

First of all, a small suggestion to everyone that starts creating/modifying bytecode
and needs more in-depth information on how the JVM internals works, the [JVM's specification documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) might look bulky and scary at first but it's invaluable help!

> Is the call to CtClass.getClassFile().getConstPool() the correct way to get a constant pool in this example?.

Yes, it is. Each Java Class has a single constant pool, so basicaly every time you need to access the constant
pool for a given class you can do `ctClass.getClassFile().getConstPool()`, although you must keep in mind the
following:

1. In javassist the constant pool field from `CtClass` is an instance field, that means that if you have two `CtClass` objects
   representing the same Class you'll have two diferrent instances of constant pool (even though they represent
   the constant pool in the actual class file). When modifying one of the `CtClass`instances you must use the
   associated constant pool instance in order to have the expected behaviour.
2. There are times where you might not have the `CtClass` but rather a `CtMethod` or a `CtField` which don't let you backtrace to the `CtClass` instance, in such cases you can use `ctMethod.getMethodInfo().getConstPool()` and `ctField.getFieldInfo().getConstPool()` to retrieve the correct constant pool.

   Since I've mentioned `CtMethod` and `CtField`, keep in mind that if you want to add attributes to any of these, it can't be through the `ClassFile` Object, but through `MethodInfo` and `FieldInfo` respectively.

> Why do we need a constant pool to create a instance of a synthetic attribute ?, or in general, of any other kind of class attributes ?

To answer this question, I'll start quoting [section 4.4 regarding JVM 7 specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4) (like I said, this documentation is quite helpful):

> Java virtual machine instructions do not rely on the runtime layout of classes, interfaces, class instances, or arrays. Instead, instructions refer to symbolic information in the constant_pool table.

With this in mind, I think the best way to shed some light on this subject is to look at a class file dump. We can achieve this by running the following command:

```
javap -s -c -p -v SomeClassFile.class
```

Javap comes with the java SDK and it's a good tool to analyse classes at this level, the explanation of each switch

- -s : Prints internal type signature
- -c : Prints byte code
- -p : Prints all class members (methods and fields, including the private ones)
- -v : Be verbose, will print tack information and class constant pool

Here's the output for `test.Test1` class that I modified via javassist to have the synthetic attribute both in the class and in the `injectedMethod`

```
Classfile /C:/development/testProject/test/Test1.class
Last modified 29/Nov/2012; size 612 bytes
MD5 checksum 858c009090bfb57d704b2eaf91c2cb75
Compiled from "Test1.java"
public class test.Test1
SourceFile: "Test1.java"
Synthetic: true
minor version: 0
major version: 50
flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER

Constant pool:
#1 = Class              #2             //  test/Test1
#2 = Utf8               test/Test1
#3 = Class              #4             //  java/lang/Object
#4 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
#5 = Utf8               <init>
#6 = Utf8               ()V
#7 = Utf8               Code
#8 = Methodref          #3.#9          //  java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
#9 = NameAndType        #5:#6          //  "<init>":()V
#10 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
#11 = Utf8               LocalVariableTable
#12 = Utf8               this
#13 = Utf8               Ltest/Test1;
#14 = Utf8               SourceFile
#15 = Utf8               Test1.java
#16 = Utf8               someInjectedMethod
#17 = Utf8               java/lang/System
#18 = Class              #17            //  java/lang/System
#19 = Utf8               out
#20 = Utf8               Ljava/io/PrintStream;
#21 = NameAndType        #19:#20        //  out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
#22 = Fieldref           #18.#21        //  java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
#23 = Utf8               injection example
#24 = String             #23            //  injection example
#25 = Utf8               java/io/PrintStream
#26 = Class              #25            //  java/io/PrintStream
#27 = Utf8               println
#28 = Utf8               (Ljava/lang/String;)V
#29 = NameAndType        #27:#28        //  println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
#30 = Methodref          #26.#29        //  java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
#31 = Utf8               RuntimeVisibleAnnotations
#32 = Utf8               Ltest/TestAnnotationToShowItInConstantTable;
#33 = Utf8               Synthetic
{
public com.qubit.augmentation.test.Test1();
Signature: ()V
flags: ACC_PUBLIC

Code:
  stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
     0: aload_0       
     1: invokespecial #8                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
     4: return        
  LineNumberTable:
    line 3: 0
  LocalVariableTable:
    Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
           0       5     0  this   Ltest/Test1;

protected void someInjectedMethod();
Signature: ()V
flags: ACC_PROTECTED

Code:
  stack=2, locals=1, args_size=1
     0: getstatic     #22                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
     3: ldc           #24                 // String injection example
     5: invokevirtual #30                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
     8: return        
RuntimeVisibleAnnotations:
  0: #32()
Synthetic: true
}
```

Notice that both the class and the method have the attribute **Synthetic: true** which mean they are Synthetic but, you the synthetic symbol must also be present in the constant pool (check #33).

Another example regarding the use of constant pool and class/method attributes is the annotation added to someInjectedMethod with runtime retention policy. The method's bytecode only has a reference to the constant pool #32 symbol, and only there you learn that
the annotation is from the type test/TestAnnotationToShowItInConstantTable;

Hope things got a bit more clear for you now.